# ExtJS 3 Checkbox BoxLabel font

Tags: extjs, checkbox, styles, label

I was wondering if it is possible to change the style (specifically the font) of a checbox box label.

```
Ext.getCmp('variablesAttributesPanel').add({xtype: 'checkbox',  id: variables[j].getTitle() + 'Checkbox', boxLabel: variableTitle, width: 362, x: 20,   y: (j *40 + 20), listeners: {check: function(){createRequestURL(i)}}});
```

This is going in a FormPanel with absolute layout.

Thanks!

ExtJS 3.3

Answer (score 1):

Old question but I don't mind.

labelStyle doesn't work in 3.4.

I use this workaround:

`boxLabel: '<span style="font-size: 12px;">' + 'My Label Text' + '</span>'`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [labelStyle or labelCls](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.Labelable) in the checkbox config.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I am using ExtJS 3.3. I do not believe there is a labelCls in 3.4. labelStyle does not seem to work for boxLabel, but fieldLabel. However I would like to use boxLabel